# C# foreach loop with key value

Tags: c#, regex, loops

In PHP I can use a foreach loop such that I have access to both the key and value for example:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
```

I have the following code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(haystack);
for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
{
     GroupCollection gc = mc[i].Groups;
     Dictionary<string, string> match = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     for (int j = 0; j < gc.Count; j++)
     {
        //here
     }
     this.matches.Add(i, match);
}
```

at `//here` I'd like to `match.add(key, value)` but I cannot figure out how to get the key from the GroupCollection, which in this case should be the name of the capturing group.  I know that `gc["goupName"].Value` contains the value of the match.

Comment: Which is the key, which is the value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In .NET, the group names are available against the `Regex` instance:

```
// outside all of the loops
string[] groupNames = regex.GetGroupNames();
```

Then you can iterate based on this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> match = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach(string groupName in groupNames) {
    match.Add(groupName, gc[groupName].Value);
}
```

Or if you want to use LINQ:

```
var match = groupNames.ToDictionary(
            groupName => groupName, groupName => gc[groupName].Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

In C# 3, you can also use LINQ to do this kind of collection processing. Classes for working with regular expressions implement only non-generic `IEnumerable`, so you need to specify a couple of types, but it's still quite elegant.

The following code gives you a collection of dictionaries that contain the group name as the key and the matched value as a value. It uses Marc's suggestion to use `ToDictionary`, except that it specifies group name as the key (I *think* that Marc's code uses matched value as the key and group name as the value).

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
var q =
  from Match mci in regex.Matches(haystack)
  select regex.GetGroupNames().ToDictionary(
    name => name, name => mci.Groups[name].Value);
```

Then you could just assign the result to your `this.matches`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the group name directly, hou have to use `GroupNameFromNumber` on the regex instance ([see doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.groupnamefromnumber.aspx)).

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(haystack);
for (int i = 0; i < mc.Count; i++)
{
     GroupCollection gc = mc[i].Groups;
     Dictionary<string, string> match = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     for (int j = 0; j < gc.Count; j++)
     {
        match.Add(regex.GroupNameFromNumber(j), gc[j].Value);
     }
     this.matches.Add(i, match);
}
```